# DRF: how to create a model property to count the number of likes and dislikes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="likes",blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="dislikes",blank=True)
```

I would like to create a property in this model which can count the number of likes and dislikes. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
@property
def interaction_count(self):
    return len(self.likes) + len(self.dislikes)
```

Sadly, calling `self.likes` doesn't give me a list like I would like it to.

Here is an example of the list I am trying to access:

[Example of likes and dislikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwOu.png) (I don't have enough reputation to embed images) (for clarification, the numbers inside this lists of likes and dislikes are user_ids.

Is there another way to access a list of all the likes associated with a particular post instance? Or perhaps is there a better way entirely to create `interaction_count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
@property
def interaction_count(self):
    return self.likes.count() + self.dislikes.count()
```